# MVC Database Options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I have developed two MVC4 applications that used EF and code first.  These were new applications where I designed the database and it made sense to have a model of the database in the application.  I am now starting a new MVC application that will use data from an existing large complicated database.  I do not want a model of the new database and all of its tables in my code.  I will just be reading and writing to a very small subset of the tables and columns.  What database options should I be using?  I have written some simpler C# apps that used this type of database connectivity below.  I'm not sure what this type of database access is called?  It's using System.Data.SqlClient.  Is this type of access out of date or not appropriate for MVC?

```
        SqlConnection con0 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        string sql0 = @"SELECT CourierMembershipUserName FROM Jobs WHERE JobStatus = 'Delivered' 
        SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand(sql0, con0);
        con0.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr0 = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction for database access for a new MVC5 application working with a large existing database where I will not be modifying the DB design, and will just be accessing a few tables and columns?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code first approach to create mapping to existing database. It is very useful when you need to map a small subset of existing database.

Comment: Hi, if the existing database has 100 tables and I only use 5 tables in my application then I could use code first to model just the 5 tables I need?  If the other 95 tables are missing from my MVC models won't EF complain?  Doesn't the database have to match exactly the entire database for EF to work?

Comment: There will be no problems if you have not links between mapped and not mapped tables